# deciding on the form of the formula in multivariate nonlinear regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression

dear members,
              lets say I have one response variable and two predictors (non linear):
Y1, the response variable, and two predictors, X1 and X2.

Using nonlinear least squares estimation, I fit the model using this formula with nls (in R):

```
nls(Y1 ~ f1(X1))
nls(Y1 ~ f2(X2))
```

f1 and f2 are functions that best fit the data.

Now lets say I want to regress Y1 with both X1 and X2, something like this:

```
nls(Y1 ~ g(X1,X2))
```

where g is a function of X1 and X2.

My question is this: is the most optimal form of g(for which the RSS is least) a function of f1 and f2? More specifically:

Is g = p(f1,f2) , where p is the required function?

OR can p take on any arbitrary formula, and we have to resort to trial and error method to detect the most optimal p(if the above case is true, the number of iterations will be less)?